# Как правильно конкатенировать массив-переменную из параметров в запуск утилиты вызываемой из powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
$aPath="$($Env:PATH);C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX64\x64"

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $aPath, 'Process')

$MYINCLUDE=@('/I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include"',`
                   '/I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um"',`
                   '/I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt"')

cl /EHsc $($MYINCLUDE -join ' ') Main.cpp
```

Comment: comma-separated list синтаксис не использует приведение типов литералов в тип array